# Debug Assertion failed in OpenCV HoughCircles Example (C++) from xstring in VS2013

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I am using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1, with OpenCV installed. I have copied the example hoghCircles() code and have built it, but I get an error in "line 1168" of xstring.

Any help would be appreciated :)

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html

Comment: show the whole, exact error, please.

Comment: also, that demo expects the image as a cmdline arg, like: prog img.jpg and never checks, if the arg was really given. might be related to that

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/OX8gGW5.png This is a link showing the error...

Comment: See my answer - it does appear to be that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't really provided much detail I am hazarding a guess here.

Are you running the debug version from within the debugger?  If so you need to go to the property pages of the project and add a command argument so it has an image to work with.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see it was taking an argument from the start, which is a link to an image. I'mm gonna modify to operate on a webcam. Thanks so much :D